# Facebook4J post message

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook4j

I seem to get this error msg when I try to use the postStatusMessage() from Facebook4J.

```
message - (#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission
```

My code:

```
 Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();


    AccessToken at = new AccessToken("");        

    // Set access token.
    facebook.setOAuthAppId("", "");
    facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(at);
    facebook.setOAuthPermissions("publish_to_groups, manage_pages, publish_pages");


    try {
        facebook.postStatusMessage("was geht");
    } catch (FacebookException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got the accesstoken from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/ and the OAuthAppId also from developers.facebook.

I am not sure if the java library is outdated/ or how can I be an admin with sufficient rights? Or is there any other easy to use java library out there where you can post to your feed?
Any help appreciated :x

Comment: You can not post in the name of a user any more, only in the name of a page. And for that, you need to use a page access token.

Comment: @misorude ty for your answer :) could I ask if you know any tutorial page/ how to get the access token from your fb page/ do you need to set any permissions also :x?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: @misorude so I think I have created a page access token, I debugged it and it looks like this: https://imgur.com/xfh5wyJ however I still get the same error msg, am I still missing something ?:x

Comment: That is still missing `publish_pages` permission.

Comment: @misorude oh ok ty, do you know how I can add this permission, I can't really find it :x

Comment: You need to request it when the page admin user logs in to your app, and then use the resulting user token to request the page token afterwards.

Comment: @misorude I think I am a retard xd how does the page admin user log in to my app :x? do you mean here imgur.com/wCQlAXF ? because for some reasons I only seem to get a few options :x

Comment: Newer apps need to be in dev mode, not live mode, otherwise you will only get a reduced set of permissions offered. (The permissions will be available in live mode, after you got your app reviewed.)

Comment: @misorude omg ty it works for dev mode now, ur actully my hero :)